# Change the ID (person) of a source to its nickname from DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2022

I have a program written in c# that retrieves the positions of Binance traders "Leaderboard".

In the 2nd column of the datagridview ("EncryptedUid" see picture) it retrieves the trader's Id but I would like to display his nickname instead of his ID

It's been several days that I try but without success. To tell you that by dint of searching, I have red eyes and burning...

Here is a piece of code, maybe someone can help me

Thanks

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxGnQ.png)

Code:

```
 private async Task<string> CreateTemplateMessage(string templateMessage, Position position)
{
  string orderType = position.Amount > 0.0 ? "BUY (LONG)" : "SELL (SHORT)";
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ENCRYPTED_UID) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.ENCRYPTED_UID, position.EncryptedUid) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.SYMBOL) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.SYMBOL, position.Symbol) : templateMessage;
  double num;
  string str3;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.AMOUNT))
  {
    str3 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str4 = templateMessage;
    string amount = FMain.AMOUNT;
    num = position.Amount;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str3 = str4.Replace(amount, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str3;
  string str5;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ENTRY_PRICE))
  {
    str5 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str6 = templateMessage;
    string entryPrice = FMain.ENTRY_PRICE;
    num = position.EntryPrice;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str5 = str6.Replace(entryPrice, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str5;
  string str7;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.MARK_PRICE))
  {
    str7 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str8 = templateMessage;
    string markPrice = FMain.MARK_PRICE;
    num = position.MarkPrice;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str7 = str8.Replace(markPrice, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str7;
  string str9;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.PNL))
  {
    str9 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str10 = templateMessage;
    string pnl = FMain.PNL;
    num = Math.Round(position.Pnl, 2);
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str9 = str10.Replace(pnl, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str9;
  string str11;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ROE))
  {
    str11 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str12 = templateMessage;
    string roe = FMain.ROE;
    num = Math.Round(position.Roe * 100.0, 2);
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str11 = str12.Replace(roe, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str11;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.UPDATE_TIME) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.UPDATE_TIME, position.UpdateTime.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ORDER_TYPE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.ORDER_TYPE, orderType) : templateMessage;
  string str1;
  if (templateMessage.Contains(FMain.TRADER_NAME))
  {
    string str2 = templateMessage;
    string oldValue = FMain.TRADER_NAME;
    string newValue = await this.GetTraderName(position.EncryptedUid);
    str1 = str2.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
    str2 = (string) null;
    oldValue = (string) null;
    newValue = (string) null;
  }
  else
    str1 = templateMessage;
  templateMessage = str1;
  str1 = (string) null;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.LEVERAGE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.LEVERAGE, position.Leverage.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  return templateMessage;
}

private async Task<string> CreateTemplateMessagePartialsOrder(
  string templateMessage,
  Position position,
  double percentSize,
  double pnl,
  double roi,
  double sizeChange)
{
  string orderType = position.Amount > 0.0 ? "BUY (LONG)" : "SELL (SHORT)";
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ENCRYPTED_UID) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.ENCRYPTED_UID, position.EncryptedUid) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.SYMBOL) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.SYMBOL, position.Symbol) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.AMOUNT) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.AMOUNT, sizeChange.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  double num;
  string str3;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ENTRY_PRICE))
  {
    str3 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str4 = templateMessage;
    string entryPrice = FMain.ENTRY_PRICE;
    num = position.EntryPrice;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str3 = str4.Replace(entryPrice, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str3;
  string str5;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.MARK_PRICE))
  {
    str5 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str6 = templateMessage;
    string markPrice = FMain.MARK_PRICE;
    num = position.MarkPrice;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str5 = str6.Replace(markPrice, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str5;
  string str7;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.PNL))
  {
    str7 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str8 = templateMessage;
    string pnl1 = FMain.PNL;
    num = Math.Round(pnl, 2);
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str7 = str8.Replace(pnl1, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str7;
  string str9;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ROE))
  {
    str9 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str10 = templateMessage;
    string roe = FMain.ROE;
    num = Math.Round(roi, 2);
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str9 = str10.Replace(roe, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str9;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.UPDATE_TIME) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.UPDATE_TIME, position.UpdateTime.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ORDER_TYPE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.ORDER_TYPE, orderType) : templateMessage;
  string str1;
  if (templateMessage.Contains(FMain.TRADER_NAME))
  {
    string str2 = templateMessage;
    string oldValue = FMain.TRADER_NAME;
    string newValue = await this.GetTraderName(position.EncryptedUid);
    str1 = str2.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
    str2 = (string) null;
    oldValue = (string) null;
    newValue = (string) null;
  }
  else
    str1 = templateMessage;
  templateMessage = str1;
  str1 = (string) null;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.PERCENT_POSITIONS) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.PERCENT_POSITIONS, percentSize.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.LEVERAGE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.LEVERAGE, position.Leverage.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  return templateMessage;
}

private async Task<string> CreateTemplateMessagePositionChange(
  Position position,
  bool isBuy,
  bool isIncrease,
  double sizeChange,
  double percentChange,
  string templateMessage)
{
  string orderType = isBuy ? "BUY" : "SELL";
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ENCRYPTED_UID) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.ENCRYPTED_UID, position.EncryptedUid) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.SYMBOL) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.SYMBOL, position.Symbol) : templateMessage;
  double num;
  string str3;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ENTRY_PRICE))
  {
    str3 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str4 = templateMessage;
    string entryPrice = FMain.ENTRY_PRICE;
    num = position.EntryPrice;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str3 = str4.Replace(entryPrice, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str3;
  string str5;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.MARK_PRICE))
  {
    str5 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str6 = templateMessage;
    string markPrice = FMain.MARK_PRICE;
    num = position.MarkPrice;
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str5 = str6.Replace(markPrice, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str5;
  string str7;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.PNL))
  {
    str7 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str8 = templateMessage;
    string pnl = FMain.PNL;
    num = Math.Round(position.Pnl, 2);
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str7 = str8.Replace(pnl, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str7;
  string str9;
  if (!templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ROE))
  {
    str9 = templateMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    string str10 = templateMessage;
    string roe = FMain.ROE;
    num = Math.Round(position.Roe * 100.0, 2);
    string newValue = num.ToString();
    str9 = str10.Replace(roe, newValue);
  }
  templateMessage = str9;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.UPDATE_TIME) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.UPDATE_TIME, position.UpdateTime.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.ORDER_TYPE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.ORDER_TYPE, orderType) : templateMessage;
  string str1;
  if (templateMessage.Contains(FMain.TRADER_NAME))
  {
    string str2 = templateMessage;
    string oldValue = FMain.TRADER_NAME;
    string newValue = await this.GetTraderName(position.EncryptedUid);
    str1 = str2.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
    str2 = (string) null;
    oldValue = (string) null;
    newValue = (string) null;
  }
  else
    str1 = templateMessage;
  templateMessage = str1;
  str1 = (string) null;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.LEVERAGE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.LEVERAGE, position.Leverage.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.POSITION_TYPE_CHANGE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.POSITION_TYPE_CHANGE, isIncrease ? "INCREASE" : "DECREASE") : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.AMOUNT_CHANGE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.AMOUNT_CHANGE, sizeChange.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  templateMessage = templateMessage.Contains(FMain.PERCENT_CHANGE) ? templateMessage.Replace(FMain.PERCENT_CHANGE, percentChange.ToString()) : templateMessage;
  return templateMessage;
}

private async Task<string> GetTraderName(string id)
{
  TraderInfo traderInfo = await BinanceApi.GetBaseInfo(id);
  return traderInfo.NickName;
}

private void dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete(
  object sender,
  DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  List<string> lstUID = this.ReplaceDownTheLine(this.txtUIDs.Text.Trim());
  Dictionary<string, bool> lstUIDColor = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
  for (int index = 0; index < lstUID.Count; ++index)
    lstUIDColor.Add(lstUID[index], index % 2 == 0);
  this.dtgvPositions.Invoke((Action) (() =>
  {
    foreach (string str in lstUID)
    {
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (IEnumerable) this.dtgvPositions.Rows)
      {
        string key = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Decimal num = 0M;
        try
        {
          num = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        bool flag;
        lstUIDColor.TryGetValue(key, out flag);
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = num >= 0M ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = flag ? FMain.COLOR_A : FMain.COLOR_B;
      }
    }
  }));
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    FMain.Log.Info((object) "Start auto check");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtUIDs.Text.Trim()))
    {
      FMain.Log.Error((object) "No data UID list");
    }
    else
    {
      bool flag = this.cbUseTeleBot.Checked;
      bool flagSendAlertNewBuyOrder = this.cbAlertNewBuyOrder.Checked;
      bool flagSendAlertNewSellOrder = this.cbAlertNewSellOrder.Checked;
      bool flagSendAlertCancelOrder = this.cbAlertCancelOrder.Checked;
      bool flagSendAlertPartials = this.cbAlertPartialsCloseOrder.Checked;
      bool flagSendAlertPositionChange = this.cbAlertPositionIncrease.Checked;
      string templateMsgLongOrder = this.txtMessageLongOrder.Text.Trim();
      string templateMsgSellOrder = this.txtMessageSellOrder.Text.Trim();
      string templateMsgCancelOrder = this.txtMessageCancelOrder.Text.Trim();
      string templateMsgPartialsOrder = this.txtMsgPartialsClosedOrder.Text.Trim();
      string templateMsgPositionChange = this.txtMessagePositionIncrease.Text.Trim();
      if (flag)
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtTelegramKey.Text.Trim()))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No have config telegram key bot");
          return;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtChannelID.Text.Trim()))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No have config channel ID");
          return;
        }
        if (flagSendAlertNewBuyOrder && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtMessageLongOrder.Text.Trim()))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No setting message new BUY order");
          return;
        }
        if (flagSendAlertNewSellOrder && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtMessageSellOrder.Text.Trim()))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No setting message new SELL order");
          return;
        }
        if (flagSendAlertCancelOrder && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtMessageCancelOrder.Text.Trim()))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No setting message new CANCEL order");
          return;
        }
        if (flagSendAlertPartials && string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateMsgPartialsOrder))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No setting message PARTIALS closed order");
          return;
        }
        if (flagSendAlertPositionChange && string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateMsgPositionChange))
        {
          FMain.Log.Error((object) "No setting message position change");
          return;
        }
      }
      List<string> lstUID = this.ReplaceDownTheLine(this.txtUIDs.Text.Trim());
      if (lstUID == null || lstUID.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Input UID list");
      TradeSetting tradeSetting = this.GetTradeSetting();
      if (tradeSetting.FlagUseTrade && this.BybitClient == null)
        throw new Exception("Please connection account to use auto trade");
      this.grSettings.Enabled = false;
      this.grTelegramSetting.Enabled = false;
      this.grTradeSetting.Enabled = false;
      this.grAccountSetting.Enabled = false;
      this.btnCreateOrder.Enabled = false;
      this.cbCheckBlance.Enabled = false;
      this.btnClosePositionTest.Enabled = false;
      this.btnStart.Enabled = false;
      this.btnStop.Enabled = true;
      this.ResetPositionCached();
      string typeTrade = this.GetTradeType();
      this.ThreadAutoCheck = new Thread((ThreadStart) (async () =>
      {
        TelegramBotService telegramBotService = new TelegramBotService(this.txtTelegramKey.Text.Trim());
        string chatId = this.txtChannelID.Text.Trim();
        while (this.ThreadAutoCheck != null)
        {
          try
          {
            List<Position> otherPositions = new List<Position>();
            foreach (string str in lstUID)
            {
              string uid = str;
              List<Position> positions = await BinanceApi.GetPositions(uid, typeTrade);
              if (positions == null || positions.Count == 0)
              {
                FMain.Log.Warn((object) ("Data position of UID = " + uid + " is empty value"));
              }
              else
              {
                otherPositions.AddRange((IEnumerable<Position>) positions);
                bool isExistUID = this.PositionsCache.ContainsKey(uid);
                if (!isExistUID)
                {
                  this.PositionsCache.Add(uid, positions);
                }
                else
                {
                  List<Position> positionOld;
                  this.PositionsCache.TryGetValue(uid, out positionOld);
                  await this.HandleOrderChange(positionOld, positions, telegramBotService, flagSendAlertNewBuyOrder, flagSendAlertNewSellOrder, flagSendAlertCancelOrder, chatId, templateMsgLongOrder, templateMsgSellOrder, templateMsgCancelOrder, flagSendAlertPartials, templateMsgPartialsOrder, tradeSetting, flagSendAlertPositionChange, templateMsgPositionChange);
                  this.PositionsCache.Remove(uid);
                  this.PositionsCache.Add(uid, positions);
                  positions = (List<Position>) null;
                  positionOld = (List<Position>) null;
                  uid = (string) null;
                }
              }
            }
            this.dtgvPositions.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
            {
              this.dtgvPositions.DataSource = (object) otherPositions;
              this.positionBindingSource.DataSource = (object) otherPositions;
            }));
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            FMain.Log.Error((object) ex);
          }
          Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(this.nmDelay.Value.ToString()) * 1000);
        }
      }));
      this.ThreadAutoCheck.IsBackground = true;
      this.ThreadAutoCheck.Start();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    this.StopCheck();
    FMain.Log.Error((object) ex.Message);
  }
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.StopCheck();


private async void btnTestTeleBot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtTelegramKey.Text.Trim()))
      FMain.Log.Error((object) "No have config telegram key bot");
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtChannelID.Text.Trim()))
    {
      FMain.Log.Error((object) "No have config channel ID");
    }
    else
    {
      TelegramBotService telegramBotService = new TelegramBotService(this.txtTelegramKey.Text.Trim());
      await telegramBotService.SendMessageAsync(this.txtChannelID.Text.Trim(), "Connection bot telegram success!!!");
      telegramBotService = (TelegramBotService) null;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    FMain.Log.Error((object) string.Format("Send bot test error: {0}", (object) ex));
  }
}

private void FMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.lbDemi.Text = "Remaining " + this.DateRemi + " days";
  this.cbbTypeFutures.SelectedText = "USDⓈ-M Futures";
}

private async void btnGetFeaturedUserRank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string typeTrade = "PERPETUAL";
    string typeFuturesValue = this.cbbTypeFutures.SelectedItem != null ? this.cbbTypeFutures.SelectedItem.ToString() : string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeFuturesValue))
      typeTrade = typeFuturesValue.Equals("COIN-M Futures") ? "DELIVERY" : "PERPETUAL";
    List<UserRank> userRanks = await BinanceApi.GetFeaturedUserRank(typeTrade);
    if (userRanks == null || userRanks.Count == 0)
    {
      FMain.Log.Warn((object) "No have data user rank!");
    }
    else
    {
      FMain.Log.Info((object) string.Format("Result get features user rank type {0}: {1} EncryptedUid", (object) typeFuturesValue, (object) userRanks.Count));
      foreach (UserRank user in userRanks)
      {
        FMain.Log.Info((object) user.toString());
        RichTextBox txtUiDs = this.txtUIDs;
        txtUiDs.Text = txtUiDs.Text + user.EncryptedUid + "\n";
      }
      typeTrade = (string) null;
      typeFuturesValue = (string) null;
      userRanks = (List<UserRank>) null;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    FMain.Log.Error((object) string.Format("Get Featured User Rank: {0}", (object) ex));
  }
}

private void dtgvPositions_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e) => this.dtgvPositions.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["No"].Value = (object) (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

private async void btnConnectAccount_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtAPIKey.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSecretKey.Text))
      throw new Exception("API key or Sercet key invalid!");
    this.Setup(this.txtAPIKey.Text.Trim(), this.txtSecretKey.Text.Trim(), this.cbUseTestnet.Checked);
    if (await this.GetInfoAccount())
      FMain.Log.Info((object) "Connect account success!");
    else
      FMain.Log.Error((object) "Connect account fail!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    FMain.Log.Error((object) ex.Message);
  }
}

private void btnCreateOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    int num = this.BybitClient != null ? (int) new FOrderTest(this.BybitClient).ShowDialog() : throw new Exception("Please connection account!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    FMain.Log.Error((object) ex.Message);
  }
}

private void cbUseAutoTrade_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.cbCopyBuyOrder.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbCopySellOrder.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.nmLeveage.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.nmPercentSizeOrder.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.nmFixedSizeOrder.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.rdFixedSize.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.rdPercentSize.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbIsolated.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbCross.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbUseStopLoss.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbUseTakeProfit.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbAutoClosePosition.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.tbTakeProfit.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.tbStopLoss.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
  this.cbAutoCreateOrderDCA.Enabled = this.cbUseAutoTrade.Checked;
}

private async void cbCheckBlance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (this.BybitClient == null)
      throw new Exception("Not connection account, please connect");
    WebCallResult<Dictionary<string, BybitBalance>> resultBalances = await this.BybitClient.InverseFuturesApi.Account.GetBalancesAsync(receiveWindow: new long?(10000L));
    Dictionary<string, BybitBalance> result = resultBalances.Success ? resultBalances.Data : throw new Exception(resultBalances.Error.Message);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, BybitBalance> keyValuePair in result)
    {
      KeyValuePair<string, BybitBalance> data = keyValuePair;
      FMain.Log.Info((object) string.Format("Coin = {0}, Available balance = {1}, Wallet balance = {2}, Equity = {3}, Total PNL = {4}", (object) data.Key, (object) data.Value.AvailableBalance, (object) data.Value.WalletBalance, (object) data.Value.Equity, (object) data.Value.TotalRealizedPnl));
      data = new KeyValuePair<string, BybitBalance>();
    }
    result = (Dictionary<string, BybitBalance>) null;
    resultBalances = (WebCallResult<Dictionary<string, BybitBalance>>) null;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    FMain.Log.Error((object) ex.Message);
  }
}

private void rdFixedSize_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.nmFixedSizeOrder.Enabled = this.rdFixedSize.Checked;
  this.nmPercentSizeOrder.Enabled = !this.rdFixedSize.Checked;
}

private void rdPercentSize_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.nmFixedSizeOrder.Enabled = !this.rdPercentSize.Checked;
  this.nmPercentSizeOrder.Enabled = this.rdPercentSize.Checked;
}

private void cbIsolated_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.cbCross.Checked = !this.cbIsolated.Checked;

private void cbCross_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.cbIsolated.Checked = !this.cbCross.Checked;

private async void btnGetLeaderboardRank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string typeTrade = "PERPETUAL";
    string typeFuturesValue = this.cbbTypeFutures.SelectedItem != null ? this.cbbTypeFutures.SelectedItem.ToString() : string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeFuturesValue))
      typeTrade = typeFuturesValue.Equals("COIN-M Futures") ? "DELIVERY" : "PERPETUAL";
    List<UserRank> userRanks = await BinanceApi.GetLeaderboardRank(typeTrade);
    if (userRanks == null || userRanks.Count == 0)
    {
      FMain.Log.Warn((object) "No have data leaderboard rank!");
    }
    else
    {
      FMain.Log.Info((object) string.Format("Result get leaderboard user rank type {0}: {1} EncryptedUid", (object) typeFuturesValue, (object) userRanks.Count));
      foreach (UserRank user in userRanks)
      {
        FMain.Log.Info((object) user.toString());
        RichTextBox txtUiDs = this.txtUIDs;
        txtUiDs.Text = txtUiDs.Text + user.EncryptedUid + "\n";
      }
      typeTrade = (string) null;
      typeFuturesValue = (string) null;
      userRanks = (List<UserRank>) null;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    FMain.Log.Error((object) string.Format("Get Featured User Rank: {0}", (object) ex));
  }
}
```

Comment: According to my observation, your code should get data from BinanceApi. You make a breakpoint at "otherPositions.AddRange((IEnumerable<Position>) positions);" to see what data is passed from BinanceApi. If there is no nickname in itself. Then you need to change BinanceApi first.
Also, try not to post such a long code on SO, you can directly upload your minimal reproducible example to github. And for your question, the structure of the database is also very important, otherwise it is impossible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.

I created a breakpoint at `otherPositions.AddRange((IEnumerable<Position>) positions);`

The data passed from BinanceApi is :

`+ [0] {UID = FB23E1A8B7E2944FAAEC6219BBDF8243, coin = DOGEUSDT, amount = 18269922, entry = 0.0857324381448, mark price = 0.07193, leveage = 5, pnl = -252169.31951046, roe = -0.95943487, time = 1683533622649}`

Comment: @zollen123 Yes, just as I thought. There is no nickname in the data sent by BinanceApi. You need to change BinanceApi. Or write a code to query nickname by yourself. Can you provide your BinanceApi code? In addition, you also need to know how to query the nickname in the database